# Escape Dollar Sign in Scrapy Xpath

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

Working with scrapy spider and its pulling wrong output for price.

HTML:

```
<span style="" class="b-product_price-standard b-product_price-standard--line_through">$350</span>
```

Xpath:

```
['price'] = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div/main/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/h1[2]/div/span[1]/text())').extract()
```

result:

```
'price': [u'\u20ac300]
```

It seems to be the "$" in the price is causing the issues. I've been digging and I can't seem to find an answer to what I thought would be a common issue, which has me thinking it might be more to it i'm missing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The result is correct (and is in euros), it's only a way to represent a character out of the ascii range with its unicode code point. try `print(u'\u20ac300')`. Follow this link: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8352&number=1024

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks! Didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use **re** instead **extract**:

```
['price'] = sel.xpath('.../span[1]/text())').re('\d+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Casimir et Hippolyte is right, the right result is retrieved, but its representation in Python looks different. But besides that, your XPath expression is not ideal.

Try not to rely on long-winded positional XPath expressions, they break very easily when there are small changes to the HTML document.

Instead, try to find elements by their attributes. Perhaps this combination of class attributes is unique? For instance

```
//span[@class = 'b-product_price-standard b-product_price-standard--line_through']
```

could work. If it does not, you have to show more of the HTML document you are selecting from.